# $\lim\inf(s_n)$ is $s_n$ is unbounded above

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(s_n)$ be an increasing sequence that is unbounded from above. Must it be the case that $\lim\inf(s_n) = +\infty$? I can't seem to come up with an example of such a sequence where $\lim\inf(s_n) < +\infty$.

Comment: If you think that $\lim\inf (s_n) = +\infty$, why not try showing it directly?

Answer (score 1):

Since $s_n$ is unbounded above and increasing we have
$\lim_n s_{n} = \infty$.

Since $s_n$ is increasing, if $k \ge n$, then $s_k \ge s_{n}$, hence $\inf_{k \ge n} s_k = s_n$, and hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{k \ge n} s_k = \liminf_n s_n = \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works.

For sake of contradiction suppose that $\liminf s_n=c$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, we have $c-\varepsilon <s_n$ for all $n\ge N_\varepsilon$, and for all $N\ge 0$ there is an $n\ge N$ so that $s_n< c+\varepsilon$. Then there is infinitely many $s_n \in (c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)$. But since $s_n$ is unbounded and increasing then there is a $N$ for which $s_n\ge S_N> c+\varepsilon$ whenever $n\ge N$, but this would imply that for all $n\ge N$, $s_n\notin (c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)$, a contradiction.

Comment: What you've shown is that, for any $c$, $\lim\inf s_n > c$, i.e. that $\lim\inf s_n = +\infty$. So setting up for a contradiction was unnecessary.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for the commentary. Yes indeed is not necessary, I've seen the argument the copper.hat and of course is easier. But in my defense =) the first thing I thought was argue by contradiction, and one day one mathematician give me the advice of not give up an argument, continuous with it and see what happens, what partial progress can be made. In this case, the argument seems to be OK (I think), however there are  easier ways. I appreciate your remark =), thanks